# Vercel using old environment variables when used with turbo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, turbo

#### Summary

This is the build process of my turbo.json
[image]

as you can clearly see I have GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS in env which means that vertical must build keeping the updated value of GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS in consideration.

while deploying the app I am using " yarn build" command and here's the screenshot of package.json

[image]

I have use --force & --no cache flag as well

my directory looks like this
[image]

also , GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS is also in  `globalEnv`
and I also tried to include turbo.json in `globalDependencies`

The issue : I once deployed the app on another team with some value of `GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS` ( lets call this x) . Now whenever I am trying to deploy the repository in any team which I create it's using the previous `GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS` (x) and not replacing it with the new environment variable(`GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS`) value I am giving to it. I have read almost all docs & tries each and every permutation and combination. I request you to please see to this matter as we are very close to our deadline and this is causing a great bottleneck to the development process. Let me know if you need further details